# Avoid invoking setget function on starting up

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a simple script like this:

```
tool
extends Node2D

export(int) var example_value=0 setget set_example_value

func set_example_value(val):
    print("Setting example_value=",val)
    
    #time/memory consuming code segment here
    
    example_value=val
```

and I set `example_value` to 3 and then exit the game engine
[image]

Now when I startup godot again the `set_example_value()` gets invoked to set the value,
Is there any way where the `example_value` will get set to 3 **without** the setter  function being invoked?

#### *why am I doing this?*

because I have a time/memory consuming function which generates sprites when the value is changed,
so when I startup godot I don't want to recreate those sprites I only want the value to be changed to what it was before closing godot

Answer (score 0):

*Please read my answer for [Play animation without invoking setget?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73929147/402022) first.*

---

The difference is that we will tell Godot to only store one of them. We can do that with `_get_property_list`. Thus, we are not going to use `export` with it.

For example we can do this:

```
var example_value := 0

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "example_value",
            type = TYPE_INT,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_EDITOR
        }
    ]
```

And the editor will show the variable because it has `PROPERTY_USAGE_EDITOR`, but it won't be stored because it does not have `PROPERTY_USAGE_STORAGE`.

If it is not stored, then when loading Godot won't find it, and won't set it (note that it might be already stored before you told Godot to not store it… Saving the resource again will fix it, or use an external editor).

---

Now the problem is that you are not saving the value at all. So we are going to have a two properties. One is only for the editor, and one is only for storage. And the storage one will not do the expensive process. Like this:

```
tool
extends Node

var example_value := 0 setget set_example_value
func set_example_value(mod_value:int) -> void:
    print("HELLO")
    example_value = mod_value


var example_value_storage:int setget set_example_value_storage, get_example_value_storage
func get_example_value_storage() -> int:
    return example_value


func set_example_value_storage(mod_value:int) -> void:
    example_value = mod_value


func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "example_value",
            type = TYPE_INT,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_EDITOR
        },
        {
            name = "example_value_storage",
            type = TYPE_INT,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_STORAGE
        }
    ]
```

---

By the way, while we are at it, checking if the value is being modified in the setter might be a good idea:

```
func set_example_value(mod_value:int) -> void:
    if example_value == mod_value:
        return

    print("HELLO")
    example_value = mod_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone wanted a simpler (but hacky) workaround

```
tool
extends Node2D

export(int) var example_value=0 setget set_example_value

var startup=true

func set_example_value(val):
    print("Setting example_value=",val)
    
    if(startup):
        example_value=val
        return
    
    #time/memory consuming code segment here
    
    example_value=val

func _process(delta):
    startup=false
    set_process(false)

func _init():
    set_process(true)
```

Comment: Notes: 1. This will work on `Node` but not `Resource`. 2. It gives you the opportunity to mess with the value before adding the node to the scene. 3. If that is OK, you could use `is_inside_tree` and `_enter_tree` (or `_ready` if what you need is not available yet in `_enter_tree`, in which also consider calling `request_ready` so it works even if the `Node` was removed from tree and added again).

Comment: @Theraot I was considering using `_enter_tree` or `_ready` but it doesn't work if I modify the script and then save the changes, which is unideal because I don't want to run the time consuming segment everytime I change/modify the script