# Play animation without invoking setget?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to play an animation of a custom property, but I don't want the setget function to be invoked

like in this case:

```
tool
extends Node2D

export(int) var example=0 setget set_example

func set_example(val):
    print("Here!")
    example=val
```

when I play the animation I just want the `example` value to be set but without invoking `set_example()`

is this or anything like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can only avoid the setter from the same class (you it by not using `self`). So, you can make a second method that sets the variable, and then use that second method externally.

```
tool
extends Node2D

export(int) var example=0 setget set_example

func set_example(val):
    print("Here!")
    example=val

func set_example_alt(val):
    example=val # The setter is not triggered here
```

**Note**: The equivalent approach in Godot 4 beta does not work.

---

If it must be a property, then you could have two properties using the same backing variable:

```
tool
extends Node2D

export(int) var example=0 setget set_example

export(int) var example_alt=0 setget set_example_alt, get_example_alt

func set_example(val):
    print("Here!")
    example=val

func get_example_alt():
    return example

func set_example_alt(val):
    example=val
```

Here the variable `example_alt` is not used. Instead, when another script (or the editor) uses `example_alt` it will be getting and setting `example`, but without triggering the setter.

*I see you have a related question: [Avoid invoking setget function on starting up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73906909/402022). I'll expand further there.*